# Command failed due to signal: Segmentation fault: 11 while building

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xcode6

In my iOS app in Xcode using Swift I am getting swift compilation issue while building.

Any idea what could cause this problem?

> CompileSwift normal i386 /Users/bewakoofmac/Desktop/MY
>   PROJECT/MYPROJECTs/MYPROJECTs/GameScene.swift
>       cd /Users/bewakoofmac/Desktop/MY PROJECT/MYPROJECTs
>       /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift
>   -frontend -c -primary-file "/Users/bewakoofmac/Desktop/MY PROJECT/MYPROJECTs/MYPROJECTs/GameScene.swift"
>   "/Users/bewakoofmac/Desktop/MY
>   PROJECT/MYPROJECTs/MYPROJECTs/GameViewController.swift"
>   "/Users/bewakoofmac/Desktop/MY
>   PROJECT/MYPROJECTs/MYPROJECTs/AppDelegate.swift"
>   "/Users/bewakoofmac/Desktop/MY
>   PROJECT/MYPROJECTs/MYPROJECTs/MyConstants.swift" -target
>   i386-apple-ios7.1 -enable-objc-interop -sdk
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.3.sdk
>   -I /Users/bewakoofmac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MYPROJECTs-ehsofqiatqieshbwuxxfnxtehjop/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator
>   -F /Users/bewakoofmac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MYPROJECTs-ehsofqiatqieshbwuxxfnxtehjop/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator
>   -F "/Users/bewakoofmac/Desktop/MY PROJECT/MYPROJECTs/MYPROJECTs" -F "/Users/bewakoofmac/Desktop/MY
>   PROJECT/MYPROJECTs/MYPROJECTs/GoogleAnalytics" -F
>   "/Users/bewakoofmac/Desktop/MY PROJECT/MYPROJECTs" -F
>   MYPROJECTs/Chartboost -g -import-objc-header
>   "/Users/bewakoofmac/Desktop/MY
>   PROJECT/MYPROJECTs/MYPROJECTs/Bridging-Header.h" -module-cache-path
>   /Users/bewakoofmac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache
>   -Xcc -I/Users/bewakoofmac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MYPROJECTs-ehsofqiatqieshbwuxxfnxtehjop/Build/Intermediates/MYPROJECTs.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MYPROJECTs.build/swift-overrides.hmap
>   -Xcc -iquote -Xcc /Users/bewakoofmac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MYPROJECTs-ehsofqiatqieshbwuxxfnxtehjop/Build/Intermediates/MYPROJECTs.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MYPROJECTs.build/MYPROJECTs-generated-files.hmap
>   -Xcc -I/Users/bewakoofmac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MYPROJECTs-ehsofqiatqieshbwuxxfnxtehjop/Build/Intermediates/MYPROJECTs.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MYPROJECTs.build/MYPROJECTs-own-target-headers.hmap
>   -Xcc -I/Users/bewakoofmac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MYPROJECTs-ehsofqiatqieshbwuxxfnxtehjop/Build/Intermediates/MYPROJECTs.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MYPROJECTs.build/MYPROJECTs-all-target-headers.hmap
>   -Xcc -iquote -Xcc /Users/bewakoofmac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MYPROJECTs-ehsofqiatqieshbwuxxfnxtehjop/Build/Intermediates/MYPROJECTs.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MYPROJECTs.build/MYPROJECTs-project-headers.hmap
>   -Xcc -I/Users/bewakoofmac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MYPROJECTs-ehsofqiatqieshbwuxxfnxtehjop/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/include
>   -Xcc -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include
>   -Xcc -I/Users/bewakoofmac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MYPROJECTs-ehsofqiatqieshbwuxxfnxtehjop/Build/Intermediates/MYPROJECTs.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MYPROJECTs.build/DerivedSources/i386
>   -Xcc -I/Users/bewakoofmac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MYPROJECTs-ehsofqiatqieshbwuxxfnxtehjop/Build/Intermediates/MYPROJECTs.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MYPROJECTs.build/DerivedSources
>   -Xcc -DDEBUG=1 -Xcc "-working-directory/Users/bewakoofmac/Desktop/MY PROJECT/MYPROJECTs" -emit-module-doc-path
>   /Users/bewakoofmac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MYPROJECTs-ehsofqiatqieshbwuxxfnxtehjop/Build/Intermediates/MYPROJECTs.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MYPROJECTs.build/Objects-normal/i386/GameScene~partial.swiftdoc
>   -Onone -module-name MYPROJECTs -emit-module-path /Users/bewakoofmac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MYPROJECTs-ehsofqiatqieshbwuxxfnxtehjop/Build/Intermediates/MYPROJECTs.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MYPROJECTs.build/Objects-normal/i386/GameScene~partial.swiftmodule
>   -serialize-diagnostics-path /Users/bewakoofmac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MYPROJECTs-ehsofqiatqieshbwuxxfnxtehjop/Build/Intermediates/MYPROJECTs.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MYPROJECTs.build/Objects-normal/i386/GameScene.dia
>   -emit-dependencies-path /Users/bewakoofmac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MYPROJECTs-ehsofqiatqieshbwuxxfnxtehjop/Build/Intermediates/MYPROJECTs.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MYPROJECTs.build/Objects-normal/i386/GameScene.d
>   -emit-reference-dependencies-path /Users/bewakoofmac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MYPROJECTs-ehsofqiatqieshbwuxxfnxtehjop/Build/Intermediates/MYPROJECTs.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MYPROJECTs.build/Objects-normal/i386/GameScene.swiftdeps
>   -o /Users/bewakoofmac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MYPROJECTs-ehsofqiatqieshbwuxxfnxtehjop/Build/Intermediates/MYPROJECTs.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MYPROJECTs.build/Objects-normal/i386/GameScene.o
>
> 0  swift                    0x000000010fec6a08
>   llvm::sys::PrintStackTrace(__sFILE*) + 40 1  swift
>   0x000000010fec6ee4 SignalHandler(int) + 452 2 
>   libsystem_platform.dylib 0x00007fff92de2f1a _sigtramp + 26 3 
>   libsystem_platform.dylib 0x00000001141c76d0 _sigtramp + 2168342480 4 
>   swift                    0x0000000110759318
>   clang::ASTReader::finishPendingActions() + 1304 5  swift
>   0x000000011075abc1 non-virtual thunk to
>   clang::ASTReader::FinishedDeserializing() + 33 6  swift
>   0x0000000110735973
>   clang::ASTReader::updateOutOfDateIdentifier(clang::IdentifierInfo&) +
>   563 7  swift                    0x00000001107c339e
>   clang::ASTWriter::WriteASTCore(clang::Sema&, llvm::StringRef,
>   std::__1::basic_string,
>   std::__1::allocator > const&, clang::Module*) + 2430 8  swift
>   0x00000001107c29eb clang::ASTWriter::WriteAST(clang::Sema&,
>   std::__1::basic_string,
>   std::__1::allocator > const&, clang::Module*, llvm::StringRef,
>   bool) + 171 9  swift                    0x00000001107f2a5f
>   clang::PCHGenerator::HandleTranslationUnit(clang::ASTContext&) + 111
>   10 swift                    0x00000001107fc2e4
>   clang::ParseAST(clang::Sema&, bool, bool) + 468 11 swift
>   0x000000011067e30e clang::FrontendAction::Execute() + 62 12 swift
>   0x0000000110656e53
>   clang::CompilerInstance::ExecuteAction(clang::FrontendAction&) + 851
>   13 swift                    0x000000010fe7d619
>   llvm::CrashRecoveryContext::RunSafely(llvm::function_ref) +
>   201 14 swift                    0x000000010fe7d760
>   RunSafelyOnThread_Dispatch(void*) + 48 15 swift
>   0x000000010fec82ed ExecuteOnThread_Dispatch(void*) + 13 16
>   libsystem_pthread.dylib  0x00007fff95ecd268 _pthread_body + 131 17
>   libsystem_pthread.dylib  0x00007fff95ecd1e5 _pthread_body + 0 18
>   libsystem_pthread.dylib  0x00007fff95ecb41d thread_start + 13 Stack
>   dump:
>   0.  parser at end of file
>
> CompileSwift normal i386 /Users/bewakoofmac/Desktop/MY
>   PROJECT/MYPROJECTs/MYPROJECTs/GameViewController.swift
>       cd /Users/bewakoofmac/Desktop/MY PROJECT/MYPROJECTs
>       /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift
>   -frontend -c "/Users/bewakoofmac/Desktop/MY PROJECT/MYPROJECTs/MYPROJECTs/GameScene.swift" -primary-file
>   "/Users/bewakoofmac/Desktop/MY
>   PROJECT/MYPROJECTs/MYPROJECTs/GameViewController.swift"
>   "/Users/bewakoofmac/Desktop/MY
>   PROJECT/MYPROJECTs/MYPROJECTs/AppDelegate.swift"
>   "/Users/bewakoofmac/Desktop/MY
>   PROJECT/MYPROJECTs/MYPROJECTs/MyConstants.swift" -target
>   i386-apple-ios7.1 -enable-objc-interop -sdk
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.3.sdk
>   -I /Users/bewakoofmac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MYPROJECTs-ehsofqiatqieshbwuxxfnxtehjop/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator
>   -F /Users/bewakoofmac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MYPROJECTs-ehsofqiatqieshbwuxxfnxtehjop/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator
>   -F "/Users/bewakoofmac/Desktop/MY PROJECT/MYPROJECTs/MYPROJECTs" -F "/Users/bewakoofmac/Desktop/MY
>   PROJECT/MYPROJECTs/MYPROJECTs/GoogleAnalytics" -F
>   "/Users/bewakoofmac/Desktop/MY PROJECT/MYPROJECTs" -F
>   MYPROJECTs/Chartboost -g -import-objc-header
>   "/Users/bewakoofmac/Desktop/MY
>   PROJECT/MYPROJECTs/MYPROJECTs/Bridging-Header.h" -module-cache-path
>   /Users/bewakoofmac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache
>   -Xcc -I/Users/bewakoofmac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MYPROJECTs-ehsofqiatqieshbwuxxfnxtehjop/Build/Intermediates/MYPROJECTs.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MYPROJECTs.build/swift-overrides.hmap
>   -Xcc -iquote -Xcc /Users/bewakoofmac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MYPROJECTs-ehsofqiatqieshbwuxxfnxtehjop/Build/Intermediates/MYPROJECTs.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MYPROJECTs.build/MYPROJECTs-generated-files.hmap
>   -Xcc -I/Users/bewakoofmac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MYPROJECTs-ehsofqiatqieshbwuxxfnxtehjop/Build/Intermediates/MYPROJECTs.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MYPROJECTs.build/MYPROJECTs-own-target-headers.hmap
>   -Xcc -I/Users/bewakoofmac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MYPROJECTs-ehsofqiatqieshbwuxxfnxtehjop/Build/Intermediates/MYPROJECTs.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MYPROJECTs.build/MYPROJECTs-all-target-headers.hmap
>   -Xcc -iquote -Xcc /Users/bewakoofmac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MYPROJECTs-ehsofqiatqieshbwuxxfnxtehjop/Build/Intermediates/MYPROJECTs.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MYPROJECTs.build/MYPROJECTs-project-headers.hmap
>   -Xcc -I/Users/bewakoofmac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MYPROJECTs-ehsofqiatqieshbwuxxfnxtehjop/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/include
>   -Xcc -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include
>   -Xcc -I/Users/bewakoofmac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MYPROJECTs-ehsofqiatqieshbwuxxfnxtehjop/Build/Intermediates/MYPROJECTs.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MYPROJECTs.build/DerivedSources/i386
>   -Xcc -I/Users/bewakoofmac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MYPROJECTs-ehsofqiatqieshbwuxxfnxtehjop/Build/Intermediates/MYPROJECTs.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MYPROJECTs.build/DerivedSources
>   -Xcc -DDEBUG=1 -Xcc "-working-directory/Users/bewakoofmac/Desktop/MY PROJECT/MYPROJECTs" -emit-module-doc-path
>   /Users/bewakoofmac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MYPROJECTs-ehsofqiatqieshbwuxxfnxtehjop/Build/Intermediates/MYPROJECTs.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MYPROJECTs.build/Objects-normal/i386/GameViewController~partial.swiftdoc
>   -Onone -module-name MYPROJECTs -emit-module-path /Users/bewakoofmac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MYPROJECTs-ehsofqiatqieshbwuxxfnxtehjop/Build/Intermediates/MYPROJECTs.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MYPROJECTs.build/Objects-normal/i386/GameViewController~partial.swiftmodule
>   -serialize-diagnostics-path /Users/bewakoofmac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MYPROJECTs-ehsofqiatqieshbwuxxfnxtehjop/Build/Intermediates/MYPROJECTs.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MYPROJECTs.build/Objects-normal/i386/GameViewController.dia
>   -emit-dependencies-path /Users/bewakoofmac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MYPROJECTs-ehsofqiatqieshbwuxxfnxtehjop/Build/Intermediates/MYPROJECTs.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MYPROJECTs.build/Objects-normal/i386/GameViewController.d
>   -emit-reference-dependencies-path /Users/bewakoofmac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MYPROJECTs-ehsofqiatqieshbwuxxfnxtehjop/Build/Intermediates/MYPROJECTs.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MYPROJECTs.build/Objects-normal/i386/GameViewController.swiftdeps
>   -o /Users/bewakoofmac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MYPROJECTs-ehsofqiatqieshbwuxxfnxtehjop/Build/Intermediates/MYPROJECTs.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MYPROJECTs.build/Objects-normal/i386/GameViewController.o
>
> 0  swift                    0x00000001073e6a08
>   llvm::sys::PrintStackTrace(__sFILE*) + 40 1  swift
>   0x00000001073e6ee4 SignalHandler(int) + 452 2 
>   libsystem_platform.dylib 0x00007fff92de2f1a _sigtramp + 26 3 
>   libsystem_platform.dylib 0x000000010b6e76d0 _sigtramp + 2022721488 4 
>   swift                    0x0000000107c79318
>   clang::ASTReader::finishPendingActions() + 1304 5  swift
>   0x0000000107c7abc1 non-virtual thunk to
>   clang::ASTReader::FinishedDeserializing() + 33 6  swift
>   0x0000000107c55973
>   clang::ASTReader::updateOutOfDateIdentifier(clang::IdentifierInfo&) +
>   563 7  swift                    0x0000000107ce339e
>   clang::ASTWriter::WriteASTCore(clang::Sema&, llvm::StringRef,
>   std::__1::basic_string,
>   std::__1::allocator > const&, clang::Module*) + 2430 8  swift
>   0x0000000107ce29eb clang::ASTWriter::WriteAST(clang::Sema&,
>   std::__1::basic_string,
>   std::__1::allocator > const&, clang::Module*, llvm::StringRef,
>   bool) + 171 9  swift                    0x0000000107d12a5f
>   clang::PCHGenerator::HandleTranslationUnit(clang::ASTContext&) + 111
>   10 swift                    0x0000000107d1c2e4
>   clang::ParseAST(clang::Sema&, bool, bool) + 468 11 swift
>   0x0000000107b9e30e clang::FrontendAction::Execute() + 62 12 swift
>   0x0000000107b76e53
>   clang::CompilerInstance::ExecuteAction(clang::FrontendAction&) + 851
>   13 swift                    0x000000010739d619
>   llvm::CrashRecoveryContext::RunSafely(llvm::function_ref) +
>   201 14 swift                    0x000000010739d760
>   RunSafelyOnThread_Dispatch(void*) + 48 15 swift
>   0x00000001073e82ed ExecuteOnThread_Dispatch(void*) + 13 16
>   libsystem_pthread.dylib  0x00007fff95ecd268 _pthread_body + 131 17
>   libsystem_pthread.dylib  0x00007fff95ecd1e5 _pthread_body + 0 18
>   libsystem_pthread.dylib  0x00007fff95ecb41d thread_start + 13 Stack
>   dump:
>   0.  parser at end of file
>
> CompileSwift normal i386 /Users/bewakoofmac/Desktop/MY
>   PROJECT/MYPROJECTs/MYPROJECTs/AppDelegate.swift
>       cd /Users/bewakoofmac/Desktop/MY PROJECT/MYPROJECTs
>       /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift
>   -frontend -c "/Users/bewakoofmac/Desktop/MY PROJECT/MYPROJECTs/MYPROJECTs/GameScene.swift"
>   "/Users/bewakoofmac/Desktop/MY
>   PROJECT/MYPROJECTs/MYPROJECTs/GameViewController.swift" -primary-file
>   "/Users/bewakoofmac/Desktop/MY
>   PROJECT/MYPROJECTs/MYPROJECTs/AppDelegate.swift"
>   "/Users/bewakoofmac/Desktop/MY
>   PROJECT/MYPROJECTs/MYPROJECTs/MyConstants.swift" -target
>   i386-apple-ios7.1 -enable-objc-interop -sdk
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.3.sdk
>   -I /Users/bewakoofmac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MYPROJECTs-ehsofqiatqieshbwuxxfnxtehjop/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator
>   -F /Users/bewakoofmac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MYPROJECTs-ehsofqiatqieshbwuxxfnxtehjop/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator
>   -F "/Users/bewakoofmac/Desktop/MY PROJECT/MYPROJECTs/MYPROJECTs" -F "/Users/bewakoofmac/Desktop/MY
>   PROJECT/MYPROJECTs/MYPROJECTs/GoogleAnalytics" -F
>   "/Users/bewakoofmac/Desktop/MY PROJECT/MYPROJECTs" -F
>   MYPROJECTs/Chartboost -g -import-objc-header
>   "/Users/bewakoofmac/Desktop/MY
>   PROJECT/MYPROJECTs/MYPROJECTs/Bridging-Header.h" -module-cache-path
>   /Users/bewakoofmac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache
>   -Xcc -I/Users/bewakoofmac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MYPROJECTs-ehsofqiatqieshbwuxxfnxtehjop/Build/Intermediates/MYPROJECTs.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MYPROJECTs.build/swift-overrides.hmap
>   -Xcc -iquote -Xcc /Users/bewakoofmac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MYPROJECTs-ehsofqiatqieshbwuxxfnxtehjop/Build/Intermediates/MYPROJECTs.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MYPROJECTs.build/MYPROJECTs-generated-files.hmap
>   -Xcc -I/Users/bewakoofmac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MYPROJECTs-ehsofqiatqieshbwuxxfnxtehjop/Build/Intermediates/MYPROJECTs.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MYPROJECTs.build/MYPROJECTs-own-target-headers.hmap
>   -Xcc -I/Users/bewakoofmac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MYPROJECTs-ehsofqiatqieshbwuxxfnxtehjop/Build/Intermediates/MYPROJECTs.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MYPROJECTs.build/MYPROJECTs-all-target-headers.hmap
>   -Xcc -iquote -Xcc /Users/bewakoofmac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MYPROJECTs-ehsofqiatqieshbwuxxfnxtehjop/Build/Intermediates/MYPROJECTs.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MYPROJECTs.build/MYPROJECTs-project-headers.hmap
>   -Xcc -I/Users/bewakoofmac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MYPROJECTs-ehsofqiatqieshbwuxxfnxtehjop/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/include
>   -Xcc -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include
>   -Xcc -I/Users/bewakoofmac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MYPROJECTs-ehsofqiatqieshbwuxxfnxtehjop/Build/Intermediates/MYPROJECTs.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MYPROJECTs.build/DerivedSources/i386
>   -Xcc -I/Users/bewakoofmac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MYPROJECTs-ehsofqiatqieshbwuxxfnxtehjop/Build/Intermediates/MYPROJECTs.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MYPROJECTs.build/DerivedSources
>   -Xcc -DDEBUG=1 -Xcc "-working-directory/Users/bewakoofmac/Desktop/MY PROJECT/MYPROJECTs" -emit-module-doc-path
>   /Users/bewakoofmac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MYPROJECTs-ehsofqiatqieshbwuxxfnxtehjop/Build/Intermediates/MYPROJECTs.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MYPROJECTs.build/Objects-normal/i386/AppDelegate~partial.swiftdoc
>   -Onone -module-name MYPROJECTs -emit-module-path /Users/bewakoofmac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MYPROJECTs-ehsofqiatqieshbwuxxfnxtehjop/Build/Intermediates/MYPROJECTs.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MYPROJECTs.build/Objects-normal/i386/AppDelegate~partial.swiftmodule
>   -serialize-diagnostics-path /Users/bewakoofmac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MYPROJECTs-ehsofqiatqieshbwuxxfnxtehjop/Build/Intermediates/MYPROJECTs.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MYPROJECTs.build/Objects-normal/i386/AppDelegate.dia
>   -emit-dependencies-path /Users/bewakoofmac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MYPROJECTs-ehsofqiatqieshbwuxxfnxtehjop/Build/Intermediates/MYPROJECTs.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MYPROJECTs.build/Objects-normal/i386/AppDelegate.d
>   -emit-reference-dependencies-path /Users/bewakoofmac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MYPROJECTs-ehsofqiatqieshbwuxxfnxtehjop/Build/Intermediates/MYPROJECTs.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MYPROJECTs.build/Objects-normal/i386/AppDelegate.swiftdeps
>   -o /Users/bewakoofmac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MYPROJECTs-ehsofqiatqieshbwuxxfnxtehjop/Build/Intermediates/MYPROJECTs.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MYPROJECTs.build/Objects-normal/i386/AppDelegate.o
>
> 0  swift                    0x0000000100a0ba08
>   llvm::sys::PrintStackTrace(__sFILE*) + 40 1  swift
>   0x0000000100a0bee4 SignalHandler(int) + 452 2 
>   libsystem_platform.dylib 0x00007fff92de2f1a _sigtramp + 26 3 
>   libsystem_platform.dylib 0x0000000104d0d6d0 _sigtramp + 1911728080 4 
>   swift                    0x000000010129e318
>   clang::ASTReader::finishPendingActions() + 1304 5  swift
>   0x000000010129fbc1 non-virtual thunk to
>   clang::ASTReader::FinishedDeserializing() + 33 6  swift
>   0x000000010127a973
>   clang::ASTReader::updateOutOfDateIdentifier(clang::IdentifierInfo&) +
>   563 7  swift                    0x000000010130839e
>   clang::ASTWriter::WriteASTCore(clang::Sema&, llvm::StringRef,
>   std::__1::basic_string,
>   std::__1::allocator > const&, clang::Module*) + 2430 8  swift
>   0x00000001013079eb clang::ASTWriter::WriteAST(clang::Sema&,
>   std::__1::basic_string,
>   std::__1::allocator > const&, clang::Module*, llvm::StringRef,
>   bool) + 171 9  swift                    0x0000000101337a5f
>   clang::PCHGenerator::HandleTranslationUnit(clang::ASTContext&) + 111
>   10 swift                    0x00000001013412e4
>   clang::ParseAST(clang::Sema&, bool, bool) + 468 11 swift
>   0x00000001011c330e clang::FrontendAction::Execute() + 62 12 swift
>   0x000000010119be53
>   clang::CompilerInstance::ExecuteAction(clang::FrontendAction&) + 851
>   13 swift                    0x00000001009c2619
>   llvm::CrashRecoveryContext::RunSafely(llvm::function_ref) +
>   201 14 swift                    0x00000001009c2760
>   RunSafelyOnThread_Dispatch(void*) + 48 15 swift
>   0x0000000100a0d2ed ExecuteOnThread_Dispatch(void*) + 13 16
>   libsystem_pthread.dylib  0x00007fff95ecd268 _pthread_body + 131 17
>   libsystem_pthread.dylib  0x00007fff95ecd1e5 _pthread_body + 0 18
>   libsystem_pthread.dylib  0x00007fff95ecb41d thread_start + 13 Stack
>   dump:
>   0.  parser at end of file
>
> CompileSwift normal i386 /Users/bewakoofmac/Desktop/MY
>   PROJECT/MYPROJECTs/MYPROJECTs/MyConstants.swift
>       cd /Users/bewakoofmac/Desktop/MY PROJECT/MYPROJECTs
>       /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift
>   -frontend -c "/Users/bewakoofmac/Desktop/MY PROJECT/MYPROJECTs/MYPROJECTs/GameScene.swift"
>   "/Users/bewakoofmac/Desktop/MY
>   PROJECT/MYPROJECTs/MYPROJECTs/GameViewController.swift"
>   "/Users/bewakoofmac/Desktop/MY
>   PROJECT/MYPROJECTs/MYPROJECTs/AppDelegate.swift" -primary-file
>   "/Users/bewakoofmac/Desktop/MY
>   PROJECT/MYPROJECTs/MYPROJECTs/MyConstants.swift" -target
>   i386-apple-ios7.1 -enable-objc-interop -sdk
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.3.sdk
>   -I /Users/bewakoofmac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MYPROJECTs-ehsofqiatqieshbwuxxfnxtehjop/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator
>   -F /Users/bewakoofmac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MYPROJECTs-ehsofqiatqieshbwuxxfnxtehjop/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator
>   -F "/Users/bewakoofmac/Desktop/MY PROJECT/MYPROJECTs/MYPROJECTs" -F "/Users/bewakoofmac/Desktop/MY
>   PROJECT/MYPROJECTs/MYPROJECTs/GoogleAnalytics" -F
>   "/Users/bewakoofmac/Desktop/MY PROJECT/MYPROJECTs" -F
>   MYPROJECTs/Chartboost -g -import-objc-header
>   "/Users/bewakoofmac/Desktop/MY
>   PROJECT/MYPROJECTs/MYPROJECTs/Bridging-Header.h" -module-cache-path
>   /Users/bewakoofmac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache
>   -Xcc -I/Users/bewakoofmac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MYPROJECTs-ehsofqiatqieshbwuxxfnxtehjop/Build/Intermediates/MYPROJECTs.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MYPROJECTs.build/swift-overrides.hmap
>   -Xcc -iquote -Xcc /Users/bewakoofmac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MYPROJECTs-ehsofqiatqieshbwuxxfnxtehjop/Build/Intermediates/MYPROJECTs.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MYPROJECTs.build/MYPROJECTs-generated-files.hmap
>   -Xcc -I/Users/bewakoofmac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MYPROJECTs-ehsofqiatqieshbwuxxfnxtehjop/Build/Intermediates/MYPROJECTs.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MYPROJECTs.build/MYPROJECTs-own-target-headers.hmap
>   -Xcc -I/Users/bewakoofmac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MYPROJECTs-ehsofqiatqieshbwuxxfnxtehjop/Build/Intermediates/MYPROJECTs.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MYPROJECTs.build/MYPROJECTs-all-target-headers.hmap
>   -Xcc -iquote -Xcc /Users/bewakoofmac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MYPROJECTs-ehsofqiatqieshbwuxxfnxtehjop/Build/Intermediates/MYPROJECTs.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MYPROJECTs.build/MYPROJECTs-project-headers.hmap
>   -Xcc -I/Users/bewakoofmac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MYPROJECTs-ehsofqiatqieshbwuxxfnxtehjop/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/include
>   -Xcc -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include
>   -Xcc -I/Users/bewakoofmac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MYPROJECTs-ehsofqiatqieshbwuxxfnxtehjop/Build/Intermediates/MYPROJECTs.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MYPROJECTs.build/DerivedSources/i386
>   -Xcc -I/Users/bewakoofmac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MYPROJECTs-ehsofqiatqieshbwuxxfnxtehjop/Build/Intermediates/MYPROJECTs.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MYPROJECTs.build/DerivedSources
>   -Xcc -DDEBUG=1 -Xcc "-working-directory/Users/bewakoofmac/Desktop/MY PROJECT/MYPROJECTs" -emit-module-doc-path
>   /Users/bewakoofmac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MYPROJECTs-ehsofqiatqieshbwuxxfnxtehjop/Build/Intermediates/MYPROJECTs.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MYPROJECTs.build/Objects-normal/i386/MyConstants~partial.swiftdoc
>   -Onone -module-name MYPROJECTs -emit-module-path /Users/bewakoofmac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MYPROJECTs-ehsofqiatqieshbwuxxfnxtehjop/Build/Intermediates/MYPROJECTs.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MYPROJECTs.build/Objects-normal/i386/MyConstants~partial.swiftmodule
>   -serialize-diagnostics-path /Users/bewakoofmac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MYPROJECTs-ehsofqiatqieshbwuxxfnxtehjop/Build/Intermediates/MYPROJECTs.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MYPROJECTs.build/Objects-normal/i386/MyConstants.dia
>   -emit-dependencies-path /Users/bewakoofmac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MYPROJECTs-ehsofqiatqieshbwuxxfnxtehjop/Build/Intermediates/MYPROJECTs.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MYPROJECTs.build/Objects-normal/i386/MyConstants.d
>   -emit-reference-dependencies-path /Users/bewakoofmac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MYPROJECTs-ehsofqiatqieshbwuxxfnxtehjop/Build/Intermediates/MYPROJECTs.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MYPROJECTs.build/Objects-normal/i386/MyConstants.swiftdeps
>   -o /Users/bewakoofmac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MYPROJECTs-ehsofqiatqieshbwuxxfnxtehjop/Build/Intermediates/MYPROJECTs.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MYPROJECTs.build/Objects-normal/i386/MyConstants.o
>
> 0  swift                    0x000000010ce18a08
>   llvm::sys::PrintStackTrace(__sFILE*) + 40 1  swift
>   0x000000010ce18ee4 SignalHandler(int) + 452 2 
>   libsystem_platform.dylib 0x00007fff92de2f1a _sigtramp + 26 3 
>   libsystem_platform.dylib 0x00000001111196d0 _sigtramp + 2117298128 4 
>   swift                    0x000000010d6ab318
>   clang::ASTReader::finishPendingActions() + 1304 5  swift
>   0x000000010d6acbc1 non-virtual thunk to
>   clang::ASTReader::FinishedDeserializing() + 33 6  swift
>   0x000000010d687973
>   clang::ASTReader::updateOutOfDateIdentifier(clang::IdentifierInfo&) +
>   563 7  swift                    0x000000010d71539e
>   clang::ASTWriter::WriteASTCore(clang::Sema&, llvm::StringRef,
>   std::__1::basic_string,
>   std::__1::allocator > const&, clang::Module*) + 2430 8  swift
>   0x000000010d7149eb clang::ASTWriter::WriteAST(clang::Sema&,
>   std::__1::basic_string,
>   std::__1::allocator > const&, clang::Module*, llvm::StringRef,
>   bool) + 171 9  swift                    0x000000010d744a5f
>   clang::PCHGenerator::HandleTranslationUnit(clang::ASTContext&) + 111
>   10 swift                    0x000000010d74e2e4
>   clang::ParseAST(clang::Sema&, bool, bool) + 468 11 swift
>   0x000000010d5d030e clang::FrontendAction::Execute() + 62 12 swift
>   0x000000010d5a8e53
>   clang::CompilerInstance::ExecuteAction(clang::FrontendAction&) + 851
>   13 swift                    0x000000010cdcf619
>   llvm::CrashRecoveryContext::RunSafely(llvm::function_ref) +
>   201 14 swift                    0x000000010cdcf760
>   RunSafelyOnThread_Dispatch(void*) + 48 15 swift
>   0x000000010ce1a2ed ExecuteOnThread_Dispatch(void*) + 13 16
>   libsystem_pthread.dylib  0x00007fff95ecd268 _pthread_body + 131 17
>   libsystem_pthread.dylib  0x00007fff95ecd1e5 _pthread_body + 0 18
>   libsystem_pthread.dylib  0x00007fff95ecb41d thread_start + 13 Stack
>   dump:
>   0.  parser at end of file
>
> Command failed due to signal: Segmentation fault: 11

Comment: Did this get solved?

Comment: @JimmyB Yep. It was a bug from Apple. They sorted it out for me.

Answer (score 0):

A segmentation fault while compiling is a bug in the compiler. Nothing you do from Xcode should cause the development environment to crash.

I suggest you upgrade to the release version of Xcode 6.3 and try again. If it still crashes on compile (not on run, on compile) then submit your app to Apple in a Radar bug report:

[**Apple Bug Reporter**](https://idmsa.apple.com/IDMSWebAuth/login.html?appIdKey=77e2a60d4bdfa6b7311c854a56505800be3c24e3a27a670098ff61b69fc5214b&sslEnabled=true&rv=3) (link)

Comment: Already on 6.3. Filed a bug on bug reporter as well. Don't know how much time they will take. My development is totally stopped due to this. :(

Comment: Have you tried the usual? Clean and rebuild/Restart Xcode/Restart your Mac?

Comment: If this is mission critical for your work you might want to use one of your developer support "incidents" to get action. They are good about starting that process quickly (although it can still take time to get to a person at Apple who has the knowledge to help you.)

Comment: Yes tried all that.  
And yes it is a critical situation so just submitted a TSI (Thanks for suggesting that).

Comment: Good luck, and please post back an answer to your question once you get resolution.  (You might also try googling various things like "CompileSwift Segmentation Fault" to try to find work-arounds while you are waiting. It's likely that you have some construct in your code that's tripping an edge case. Simply by restructuring your code slightly you might be able to avoid the problem.)

Comment: Thanks. yes obviously would do that. And yes would continue googling untill the issue get resolved. Do let me know if you have any other ideas as well.

Comment: @AnthonyM, you should put your comment on the OPs question, not on my answer to it.